# Campogram not bein generated

Tags: r, ggplot2

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SVUQ2lmaiz5kXYP3uYPjaxC9NusF-_Vu/view?usp=sharing
I have to create a fieldgram with just the passes of an athlete in a specific soccer match, the commands used in another example are exactly these. However, the compogram is not being generated and at the end the error appears: "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'x' not found".

```
library(ggplot2)
library(readr)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggforce)
library(ggExtra)

full_data <- read_delim("full_data.txt", ";", locale =
                          locale(decimal_mark = ","), trim_ws = TRUE)
View(full_data)

jugador_elegido <- c("Sergio Busquets")
rival_elegido <- c("Real Madrid")
donde <- c("2")
evento_elegido <- c("Pass All")
data_player <- subset(full_data, nombre_jugador ==
jugador_elegido & Rival == rival_elegido & Local ==
donde & Sección == evento_elegido)

player_scatter_plot <- ggplot() +
  geom_point(data_player, mapping = aes(x = x1 - 58.015, y = y1,
  fill = factor(data_player$Resultado)),
                shape = 21,
                size = 5) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = NULL)) +
  geom_rect(mapping = aes(xmin = 0.0, xmax = 596.97, ymin = 50.5,
ymax = 446.5), color = "#00529f", fill = NA, alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_rect(mapping = aes(xmin = 0.0, xmax = 91.935, ymin =
128.975, ymax = 368.025), color = "#00529f", fill = NA,
alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_rect(mapping = aes(xmin = 505.035, xmax = 596.97, ymin =
128.975, ymax = 368.025), color ="#00529f", fill = NA, alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_rect(mapping = aes(xmin = 0.0, xmax = 29.858, ymin = 195,
ymax = 302.0), color ="#00529f", fill = NA, alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_rect(mapping = aes(xmin = 567.112, xmax = 596.97, ymin =
195, ymax = 302.0), color ="#00529f", fill = NA, alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_linerange(aes(x = 298.485, ymin = 50.5, ymax = 446.5),
color = "#00529f") +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = 66.33, y = 248.5), size = 1, color
= "#00529f") +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = 530.64, y = 248.5), size = 1,
color = "#00529f") +
  geom_circle(mapping = aes(x0 = 298.485, y0 = 248.5, r = 52),
color = "#00529f") +
  coord_fixed() +
  theme_no_axes(base.theme = theme_bw()) +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.5, 0.04),
        legend.box = "horizontal",
        legend.direction = "horizontal",
        legend.box.background = element_rect(fill =
"transparent", colour = "transparent"),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 14),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank()) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,647.47), expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,497), expand = c(0,0))

ggExtra::ggMarginal(player_scatter_plot,
                    x = x1 - 258.015,
                    y = y1,
                    type = "histogram",
                    xparams = list(breaks = seq(0,600,50),
                                   color = "#00529f"),
                    yparams = list(breaks = seq(50,450,50),
                                   color = "#00529f")
                    )
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: I put the link of drive in the top

Comment: There were several errors in your txt file. Only one of these filters is legitimate. For example, Busquets' name never appears in the field `nombre_jugador`. The name does appear in the `Jugador` field, but not with the first name. If I change each of your filters (except `Local`, because the options are 0 and 1—I have no idea what you were looking for) -- i.e., `data_player = full_data[full_data$Rival == "Real Madrid" & full_data$Sección == "Passes_All" & full_data$Jugador == "Busquets", ]` it returned 82 rows. When I fixed the filter your plot works fine.